# What is the drawing sequence of the entities in the scene graph in Qt3D?

Tags: qt3d

Recently, I tried to realize a semi transparent surface in Qt3D. I put this semi transparent surface in the scene graph in Qt3D together with many other entities that should be draw. However, I found that the drawing order of the surface is not fixed, which seriously affect the blending effect.

How can I know the drawing sequence of the entities in the scene graph in Qt3D? Also, how can I make sure that my semi transparent surface was drawn last?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the class [`QSortPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qt3drender-qsortpolicy.html). You can set the sorting policy there to back to front, to draw the transparent surface last. Although, according to the documentation, the drawing order depends on when the entities appear in the scene graph, when no sorting policy is present.

Other than that, I found a frame/scene graph in Qt3D that showcases a transparent object here: https://github.com/alpqr/q3dpostproc. It's written in QML but you should be able to transfer it to C++ without much work.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The program in the repository that I linked or your own program? How do you remove entities?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried and it now works well. But I found that the back to front sort policy is not what I want. And I just want the draw order to be the order that the entity is in the scene graph. So the sort policy is not needed.

Comment: Below is the method I used to remove an entity from the scene graph dynamically.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i9nf5f92JzgzECMofRIc-Q5LiyCVysF-/view?usp=sharing
Thank you.

Comment: Like I said above: "the drawing order depends on when the entities appear in the scene graph, when no sorting policy is present", i.e. without the policy this is exactly what you want.

Comment: "If QSortPolicy is not present in the FrameGraph, entities are drawn in the order they appear in the entity hierarchy." - this is stated in the documentation of QSortPolicy.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I didn't use the QSortPolicy. And I have put the semi transparent surface at the end of the scene graph. I have checked that through printing out the whole scene graph tree. My current problems is, most of the time, the semi transparent surfance can be correctly drawn, but sometimes it is not correctly drawn. Could this be caused by the dynamically adding and removing entities in the scene graph?

Comment: I think these comments are leading too far off the original question. I'd suggest you accept my answer, as it answers the actual question and open a new question with more details on your new problem, i.e. describe your setup and what you want to achieve, provide a minimally working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and screenshots of your issue.